# On running an exe, Windows isn't recognizing that I have jre 1.7

Tags: windows, installation, java, cmd.exe

**The Context:**  I'm trying to run an .exe (it's the installer for glassfish 3, if you're curious).  When I run it from the GUI, it throws

> This application needs version 1.6 or higher of JRE...If you already have the required JRE installed, try rerunning this application with the following usage: 'ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe' -j

So first of all, I do have JRE 1.7 installed, and yes it is in the environment variable `Path`.

- JAVA_HOME: `c:\develop\java\jdk1.7.0_75`
- Path: `...%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...`

Second of all, Windows does give me a message saying I can Reinstall Using Recommended Settings.  But doing that still gives me the same error.  So I decided to try to run the command that way from the cmd.

**The Problem:** I want to run the .exe in the way it is recommending.  I don't know if I'm formatting it exactly as the message intended.  When I run `c:\develop\ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j <c:/develop/java/jdk1.7.0_75`, I get *Access is denied*.

I went into properties on both the exe file, and the jre folder, and set my username to have all access, but I still get that message.

**Question 1:** Am I running the command with the correct syntax?

**Question 2:**  What is the name of this command that I'm using to run this exe?  Where is the documentation of it so I could better understand the options used in it (like `-j`)?

**Question 3:** Why am I getting *Access is denied* and how can I fix it?

**Question 4:** (Back to the original problem that started this), any idea why Windows isn't realizing that I have jre 1.7?

Comment: Try it without the < sign prepended on the path. That looks like a typo to me; somebody was trying to write `<Java(TM) installation directory>` and forgot to close the angle bracket. Also, if that doesn't work, try specifying the bin folder or even the path to java.exe itself, rather than just the install folder.

Comment: @DavidPostill & CBHacking that was it, thank you...also, let me know if you have any idea on question 2.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for...I was confused because I assumed I should be looking for documentation to a windows cmd command, not the glassfish install command.

Comment: @DavidPostill it's not needed, although I am curious if you have any idea, since the environment variables should tell it where it is.

Comment: Windows doesn’t care about Java. The program does. And it’s the program that’s responsible for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to run the .exe in the way it is recommending.

> I don't know if I'm formatting it exactly as the message intended. When I run `c:\develop\ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j <c:/develop/java/jdk1.7.0_75`, I get Access is denied.

---

**Question 1: Am I running the command with the correct syntax?**

No. You have a `<` (which is a [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) operator) at the start of:

```
<c:/develop/java/jdk1.7.0_75
```

You need to remove the `<` and run:

```
c:\develop\ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j c:/develop/java/jdk1.7.0_75
```

---

**Question 2: What is the name of this command that I'm using to run this exe?**

> Where is the documentation of it so I could better understand the options used in it (like -j)?

The command name is `ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe`. The command line options are documented at [Installation Command-Line Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/ghufl.html):

- `-j javahome`

  Use this directory for the JDK software installation.

---

**Question 3: Why am I getting Access is denied and how can I fix it?**

See the answer to Question 1. The command line you were using had the wrong syntax.

---

**Question 4: Any idea why Windows isn't realizing that I have jre 1.7?**

See the answers to Question 1 and 2. When you use the correct command the installer can find the JDK installation directory.